# Adding driving time in distance calculation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using this code as a starting point but it only calculates the driving distance between two places and not the driving time.

What would I need to add to the js to get the driving time as well?

I have, btw, already looked at Google Developer's Guide but haven't been able to figure it out.

https://codepen.io/youfoundron/pen/GIlvp

JS:

```
$(function() {

 function calculateDistance(origin, destination) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
  }

  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      $('#result').html(err);
    } else {
      var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
      var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
      if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " 
                          + origin + " and " + destination);
      } else {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
        var distance_value = distance.value;
        var distance_text = distance.text;
        var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
        $('#result').html("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + " to drive.");
      }
    }
  }

  $('#distance_form').submit(function(e){
      event.preventDefault();
      var origin = $('#origin').val();
      var destination = $('#destination').val();
      var distance_text = calculateDistance(origin, destination);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `duration.text` in the `DistanceMatrixResponse' Object` so change your `else block` from:

```
 else {
    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
    var distance_value = distance.value;
    var distance_text = distance.text;
    var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
    $('#result').html("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + " to drive.");
  }
```

To:

```
 else {
    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
    var distance_value = distance.value;
    var distance_text = distance.text;

    // Add a variable here to store the duration
    var duration_time = duration.text; 

    var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
    $('#result').html("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + duration_time " to drive.");
  }
```

duration.text must be added to the `ResponseObject` as:
`result[0].duration.text`

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#DistanceMatrixResponseElement) the response element that you get the distance from also includes the duration:

> duration  
>   Type:  Duration
>   The duration for this origin-destination pairing. This property may be undefined as the duration may be unknown.

That property has the following properties:

> Properties
>   text  
>   Type:  string
>   A string representation of the duration value.
>   value 
>   Type:  number
>   The duration in seconds.

Add the version you like to the callback function (probably want text):

```
  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      $('#result').html(err);
    } else {
      var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
      var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
      if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " 
                          + origin + " and " + destination);
      } else {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
        var distance_value = distance.value;
        var distance_text = distance.text;
        var duration_value = duration.value;
        var duration_text = duration.text;
        var kilometer = distance_text.substring(0, distance_text.length - 3);
        $('#result').html("It is " + kilometer + " kilometer from " + origin + " to " + destination + " and it takes " + duration_text + " to drive.");
      }
    }
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wo8k4qep/2/)

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the form post, not the code in the answer.